When trying to view shading on model, it goes black as well as rendering a shaded view, I see nothing. Any way to fix this?
I'm new to Blender and 3D modeling as a whole. When clicking on Viewport Shading, the model suddenly turns black. (I'm trying to follow that donut tutorial). Rendering that model also just gives me a blank screen. I've tried lowering my resolution, auto smooth does not show up in the data tab (these are some suggestions I've seen others give). I cannot figure out how to fix this, please help.

It's probably something simple but we can't see your settings so it would help if you could share your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
